# Why n-Butane has high B. p than iso-Pentane although both have equal no. of carbon atoms along the chain length?

Tags: transition-metals

n-Butane =B. p =-1 oC
iso pentane =b. p= 28 oC

Answer (score 1):

Pentanes are heavier than butanes, whatever their geometry. So the boiling point of pentanes are higher. This is a general tendency in the series of hydrocarbons. Pentanes and butanes are good examples to show that the chain length has not the most important effect on the boiling point.

*n*-Pentane boils at $\pu{36°C}$, 2,2-dimethylpropane at $\pu{9.5°C}$. So all pentanes boil between $\pu{9.5°C}$ and $\pu{36°C}$.

In contrast, all butanes boil under $\pu{0°C}$. *n*-Butane boils at $\pu{-1°C}$ and isobutane at $\pu{-10°C}$.